# Jersey not triggering ContainerRequestFilter

Tags: jersey, grizzly

I'm trying to use a ContainerRequestFilter to enforce some authentication on a Grizzly based Jersey application.

I create my own resource config by extending PackagesResourceConfig:

```
public class MainResourceConfig extends PackagesResourceConfig {

    public MainResourceConfig() {
        super("za.co.quinn.ws");
        Map<String, Object> properties = getProperties();
        properties.put(
                "com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilter",
                "com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter;" + MainRequestFilter.class.getName()
        );
        properties.put(
                "com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters",
                "com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter;" + MainResponseFilter.class.getName()
        );
    }
}
```

The request filter is for authentication:

```
@Inject
Authorization authorization;

@Override
public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {

    if (!request.getRequestUri().getPath().endsWith(".wadl"))
        authorization.authorize(request);

    return request;
}
```

The response filter is for headers:

```
@Override
public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest request, ContainerResponse response) {

    response.getHttpHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.getHttpHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, HEAD, POST, DELETE, PUT");
    response.getHttpHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Content-Type");

    return response;
}
```

The MainResponseFilter does get triggered but not the ContainerRequestFilter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "The MainResponseFilter does get triggered but not the ContainerRequestFilter."

Look at your properties, mainly the send of it, and compare them

```
...container.ContainerRequestFilter"

...container.ContainerResponseFilters"
```

You're missing an `s` for the request filters. To avoid misspellings like this, you can use constants

- [`ResourceConfig.PROPERTY_CONTAINER_REQUEST_FILTERS`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.19/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/core/ResourceConfig.html#PROPERTY_CONTAINER_REQUEST_FILTERS)
- [`ResourceConfig.PROPERTY_CONTAINER_RESPONSE_FILTERS`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.19/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/core/ResourceConfig.html#PROPERTY_CONTAINER_RESPONSE_FILTERS)

You could also do

```
getContainerRequestFilters().add(new YourRequestFilter());
getContainerResponseFilters().add(new YourResponseFilter());
```